# Would the One Ring even work for anyone but Sauron?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-one-ring

The temptation of the One Ring, we quickly learn, is always tied up with power: each character's fantasies of possessing it seem to be about what they would do with great power. Even Sam, as I recall, imagines the power to create great huge sweeping gardens. Boromir wants the power to save Gondor, etc.

But does the One Ring actually convey power to anyone but Sauron? It actually seems to diminish its bearers: Bilbo feels "thin" and "stretched", Sméagol becomes the wretched Gollum, Frodo is never quite the same even after it is destroyed. None of them seem more "powerful," even in the abstract way that magic-users in Tolkien operate. No mention is made, that I can recall, of a Ringbearer having greater stature or authority, or of people naturally following them or obeying their commands, while they possess the Ring.

The accepted answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23352/is-the-one-ring-only-loyal-to-sauron-or-would-it-serve-any-powerful-being) implies that a being as powerful as Gandalf could dominate the Ring and break Sauron's hold over it, but even then Tolkien says that "It would have been the master in the end", and his descriptions of a Ringbearing Gandalf sound pretty much like Gandalf is using his own powers, not terribly augmented by the Ring:

> [Gandalf] would have remained 'righteous', but self-righteous. He would have continued to rule and order things for 'good', and the benefit of his subjects according to his wisdom (which was and would have remained great).

Now that sounds out of character for a being as humble as Gandalf, but it doesn't actually sound like something he would have been unable to do before. It's a twisted motive, but not really an enhanced power.

Pretty much everyone in Middle-earth agrees that the One Ring will corrupt you, but they all seem to agree that it DOES convey great power even so. Why? Do we ever see any actual, "positive" effects from possessing the One Ring?

Comment: I need to add that in 30+ years of reading Tolkien this interpretation never even occurred to me, but it just makes so much sense: it's obviously *exactly* the way that the Ring works.  Well done again.

Comment: this begs the question - would it even work for Sauron?  It sure didn't help him when he wore it against Gil-Galad and the like.

Comment: @Oldcat : (Sauron - PowerHePutInTheRing) + PowerHePutInTheRing == Sauron; the Ring wouldn't convey any extra power to Sauron aside from control over the other Rings (speaking of which, where were the Nazgul during the Battle of the Last Alliance anyway?) (and one could argue that it did help him avoid destruction since the Ring survived, and so most of Sauron was also able to survive).

Comment: @JimmyShelter: Sauron would have survived regardless, as one of the Ainur. The Ring is what made him vulnerable: the destruction of the Ring meant that Sauron would be reduced to almost nothing.

Comment: I think the Nazgul were created after that battle - they were kings of men from the North.

Comment: Interesting question - but I wouldn't exactly describe Gandalf as humble.

Comment: @Oldcat - Tale of Years for Second Age 2251 - "*Tar-Atanamir takes the sceptre. Rebellion and division of the Númenoreans begins. About this time the Nazgûl or Ringwraiths, slaves of the Nine Rings, first appear*" - the Nazgul were therefore around for almost 1200 years before the Last Alliance.

Comment: Makes you wonder what the Numenorians thought of those 9 wraiths hanging around with him while he was captured by them. And how he managed to get the ring out after Numenor was drowned and he lost his pretty body.

Comment: @Oldcat - the latter has already been asked and answered: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26833/the-one-ring-and-numenor/26836

Comment: This makes me wonder why the Ring even grants the user invisibility.  It clearly doesn't do so at all times; when Sauron wears it, he remains visible.  And invisibility can't really be interpreted as granting the wielder great powers.  So why?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AOIi9SjJvgU tickled me with its description of the ring ` ... fight for the one ring, which does nothing but turn you into an invisible crack addict`

Comment: `It actually seems to diminish its bearers` - Bilbo may be "stretched" and Gollum "wretched" but they're both in much better shape than they would've been *without* the Ring...

Comment: @Rawling There's a big difference between preservation and enhancement.  Bilbo and Gollum were preserved (kind of) and saved (kind of) from the ravages of old age, but it's clear that Ring-lust evokes fantasies of *enhanced* power, of being able to do things you'd *never* have been able to do without the Ring.

Comment: @asteri I suspect it may have been based on the Ring of Gyges, which allowed the wearer to avoid the negative consequences of their actions.

Comment: @asteri : I assume that's only because Sauron can control the invisibility. For anyone else, it's automatic.

Comment: @Rawling  "Much better shape" only if your sole standard is long life.  The Ringwraiths have lived WAY longer than Men are supposed to, but I'd hardly say they're "in much better shape" than their peers.

Comment: Is that true? Did not the Ring convey this power to Sam in Mordor, when he wore the ring that one time?

Comment: @user867 Surely '(Sauron - PowerHePutInTheRing) + PowerHePutInTheRing > Sauron' is more likely, why else would Sauron take the trouble of creating The Ring? Boredom, perhaps, but, as we've seen, it was also a risk, putting that so much of himself into an object that might be stolen or lost.

Comment: @ElisevanLooij I agree, but I'm not sure why you addressed that comment to me; It seems unrelated to what I was saying. Did you mean to at-mention someone else?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Yes. While the deceit of the ring was to offer imaginations of *supreme* power, it *did* in fact, absolutely, one hundred percent, confer real power upon its wielder - just not *supreme* power, which not even Sauron possessed. The other answer is incorrect. There are examples of the Ring's powers - chiefly the domination of other wills, but also the understanding of "the thought behind speech" - being used in-story. And here is what Tolkien said:

> But to achieve this he had been obliged to let a great part of his own inherent power (a frequent and very significant motive in myth and fairy-story) pass into the One Ring. While he wore it, his power on earth was actually enhanced. But even if he did not wear it, that power existed and was in 'rapport' with himself: he was not 'diminished'. Unless some other seized it and became possessed of it. If that happened, the new possessor could (if sufficiently strong and heroic by nature) challenge Sauron, **become master of all that he had learned or done since the making of the One Ring, and so overthrow him and usurp his place.**

The reason we don't see the effects of the Ring all the time is threefold:

1. Because wielding the Ring takes effort and practice. "Before you could use that power you would need to become far stronger, and to train your will to the domination of others", in the words of Galadriel. In fact, she says that without this training, the Ring would destroy Frodo.
2. You have to actually claim the Ring as your own to truly use its power. Frodo and Bilbo never did this, and maybe Gollum just never had the strength. The moment Frodo claimed the Ring for his own, Sauron **knew**. "And far away, even as Frodo put on the Ring and claimed it for his own, even in Sammath Naur the very heart of his realm, the Power in Barad-Dur was shaken, and the Tower trembled from its foundations to its proud and bitter crown. The Dark Lord was suddenly aware of him[...]
3. The power of the Ring is not absolute. Sauron was able to dominate and subvert the Numenoreans only with time and subtlety. And the reason Sauron had to do that? "So great was the might and splendour of the Númenóreans that Sauron’s own servants deserted him." So even Sauron wielding the Ring wasn't able to control his own servants under some circumstances.

Bilbo and Gollum are actually good examples of the power of the Ring: forcing a mortal to stay alive is **tremendous**. The Ring doesn't grant you courage, strength, wisdom, or magic spells. It gives you the power to dominate others, strengthens your native ability to read minds, and, if you're  a mortal, forces you to stay alive - not even the Ring can fundamentally change fate decreed by Illuvatar; the Ring is already stretching The Rules quite a bit here.

The Ring granted Frodo and Sam its chief power and purpose - domination over others - on several occasions, to subdue Gollum and to terrify Orcs. This was before Frodo even claimed the Ring.

> Then suddenly, as before under the eaves of the Emyn Muil, Sam saw these two rivals with other vision. A crouching shape, scarcely more than the shadow of a living thing, a creature now wholly ruined and defeated, yet filled with a hideous lust and rage; and before it stood stern, untouchable now by pity, a figure robed in white, but at its breast it held a wheel of fire. Out of the fire there spoke a commanding voice.
>
> ‘Begone, and trouble me no more! If you touch me ever again, you shall be cast yourself into the Fire of Doom.’
>
> The crouching shape backed away, terror in its blinking eyes, and yet at the same time insatiable desire.
>
> Then the vision passed and Sam saw Frodo standing, hand on breast, his breath coming in great gasps, and Gollum at his feet, resting on his knees with his wide-splayed hands upon the ground.

Or:

> For what it saw was not a small frightened hobbit trying to hold a steady sword: it saw a great silent shape, cloaked in a grey shadow, looming against the wavering light behind; in one hand it held a sword, the very light of which was a bitter pain, the other was clutched at its breast, but held concealed some nameless menace of power and doom. For a moment the Orc crouched, and then with a hideous yelp of fear it turned and fled back as it had come.

We also have some examples of what *would* have happened, from Tolkien's letters. For example, what if Gollum hadn't been there at Mount Doom?

> Frodo too would then probably, if not attacked, have had to take the same way: cast himself with the Ring into the abyss. If not he would of course have completely failed. It is an interesting problem: how Sauron would have acted or the claimant have resisted. Sauron sent at once the Ringwraiths. They were naturally fully instructed, and in no way deceived as to the real lordship of the Ring. The wearer would not be invisible to them, but the reverse; and the more vulnerable to their weapons. But the situation was now different to that under Weathertop, where Frodo acted merely in fear and wished only to use (in vain) the Ring's subsidiary power of conferring invisibility. He had grown since then. Would they have been immune from its power if he claimed it as an **instrument of command and domination?**
> Not wholly. I do not think they could have attacked him with violence, nor laid hold upon him or taken him captive; they would have obeyed or feigned to obey any minor commands of his that did not interfere with their errand – laid upon them by Sauron, who still through their nine rings (which he held) had primary control of their wills. That errand was to remove Frodo from the Crack. Once he lost the power or opportunity to destroy the Ring, the end could not be in doubt – saving help from outside, which was hardly even remotely possible.
> Frodo had become a considerable person, but of a special kind: in spiritual enlargement rather than in increase of physical or mental power; his will was much stronger than it had been, but so far it had been exercised in resisting not using the Ring and with the object of destroying it. He needed time, much time, before he could control the Ring or (which in such a case is the same) before it could control him; before his will and arrogance could grow to a stature in which **he could dominate other major hostile wills.** Even so for a long time his acts and commands would still have to seem 'good' to him, to be for the benefit of others beside himself.

It also granted Sam the ability to understand the speech of Orcs, and Frodo was able to understand Galadriel's thoughts: "[Frodo] perceived my thought more clearly than many who are accounted wise."

However, in the end, the Ring - as essentially distilled Sauron and "power" - would have turned anyone who used it "evil." From Tolkien's letters:

> In any case Elrond or Galadriel would have proceeded in the policy now adopted by Sauron: they would have built up an empire with great and **absolutely subservient** generals and armies and engines of war, until they could challenge Sauron and destroy him by force.
>
> Confrontation of Sauron alone, unaided, self to self was not contemplated. One can imagine the scene in which Gandalf, say, was placed in such a position. It would be a delicate balance. On one side the true allegiance of the Ring to Sauron; on the other superior strength because Sauron was not actually in possession, and perhaps also because he was weakened by long corruption and expenditure of will in dominating inferiors. If Gandalf proved the victor, the result would have been for Sauron the same as the destruction of the Ring; for him it would have been destroyed, taken from him for ever. But the Ring and all its works would have endured. It would have been the master in the end.
>
> Gandalf as Ring-Lord would have been far worse than Sauron. He would have remained ‘righteous’, but self-righteous. He would have continued to rule and order things for ‘good’, and the benefit of his subjects according to his wisdom (which was and would have remained great)."

EDIT: To clarify, the One Ring did enhance Sauron's powers as well, and it was not created solely to control the wielders of the other Great Rings.

From Tolkien's letters, the Ring was created in "his [Sauron's] effort (largely unsuccessful) to enslave the Elves, *and* in his desire to establish a control over the minds and wills of his servants."

Additionally, we know Sauron used the One Ring to subjugate the Numenoreans. From Letter 211:

> He naturally had the One Ring, and so very soon dominated the minds and wills of most of the Númenóreans.

Thus, the Ring could be used by Sauron used to dominate the minds and wills of people who were **not** wearing other rings. Wielding another one of the Great Rings only seems to have made you especially vulnerable.

The reason we didn't see any amazing tricks from Frodo or Sam (beyond terrifying and subjugating Gollum, Orcs, etc.) is explained in the book, and in one of my quotes above. Frodo asks Galadriel why he can't use the Ring to know the thoughts of the wielders of the Three:

> 'Only thrice have you set the Ring upon your finger since you knew what you possessed. Do not try! It would destroy you. Did not Gandalf tell you the rings give power according to the measure of their possessor? Before you could use that power you would need to become far stronger, and train your will to the domination of others.'

Using the power of the Ring is not as simple as "put it on, get amazing results."

Comment: “Motive” should probably be “motif” if I'm not  misinterpreting the reading.

Comment: Another minor typo in the last quote, ``Do no try'' --- not?

Comment: @Shamshiel - you haven't explained the "essential deceit of the Ring" line.  Until you do so, your answer seems dubious.

Comment: @JimmyShelter: It needs no explanation - the Ring gives imaginations of *supreme* power (as Tolkien said, it is the will to mere power given form.)  Clearly it does not give that to anyone, not even Sauron: his own servants fled before the Numenoreans, and he expended huge amounts of time and energy on gaining power over the Numenoreans. But that does mean the Ring does *not* grant power; it most certainly does. We have many actual examples, the words of Tolkien, and the words characters to prove it.

Comment: @JimmyShelter: To expand on that, the Ring "wants" to be used. To Tolkien, the Ring was "the will to mere power, seeking to make itself objective by physical force and mechanism, and so also inevitably by lies." I'll add that to my answer if you think it is relevant; I am afraid it is growing too long.

Comment: @Shamshiel - did Tolkien say anything more about "Gandalf as Ring-lord"?  He says Gandalf would have been "far worse" than Sauron if he had the Ring, but the worst thing he would do, according to the portion of the letter you quoted, is be "self righteous" and order things "for the good" - which doesn't sound so bad.  He must have gone on to explain why a self righteous but benevolent Gandalf as Ring-lord would have been worse than Sauron.

Comment: @WadCheber: The remaining part of that letter is: [The draft ends here. In the margin Tolkien wrote: ‘Thus while Sauron multiplied [illegible word] evil, he left “good” clearly distinguishable from it. Gandalf would have made good detestable and seem evil.’]

Comment: That argument strikes me as incredibly flimsy.  But if he said it, I guess most would say he was right.  I'll have to let him off the hook by imagining that he was about to explain himself properly but got distracted and never finished his thought.  Because this argument sounds like "he'd be as self righteous as all rulers, but whereas most rulers are mostly evil and help only themselves and their lackeys, he'd be all good and help everyone.  Thus he'd be a far better ruler than has ever existed on earth, but for some reason, that makes him worse than Satan and superHitler combined"

Comment: I've always found it a bit annoying that he didn't elaborate further on his theory that Gandalf would've been worse. I think however what Tolkien was saying here is he would've essentially been filled with the same intentions as Sauron, only his wisdom would've made him more dangerous to Middle Earth. Sauron let's not forget originally followed Melkor because he lust for order and perfection in all things eventually becoming _self-righteous_ because he took it upon himself to do these things for himself and others regardless of their opposition.

Comment: I would think Gandalf would be similar, only because of his wisdom, he would push it to greater heights. _"No you can't eat salted pork because it's not good for you, and if you defy my logic I'll take your head off"_. Naturally this would horrify most hobbits and dwarves to the point of suicide, since they love salted pork ;)

Comment: @WadCheber let's start by remembering that no emperor on Earth ever considers himself evil. And then remember that, for example, Soviet Union was based (among other things) on the slogan of "from each according to his abilities, to each according to his needs". This lead to millions of dead in prison and labour camps, and even at the end of 1970ies people got sentenced to 10 years hard labour for just *reading the wrong books*. The examples of good going  astray when possessing absolute power are numerous in history.

Comment: I'd need to see Frodo dominate someone who was not already terrified of Sauron, as every Orc surely must have been. Sauron's ring, claimed by Frodo, should scare orcs, because they are very wisely scared of Sauron. Frodo steadily became more assertive, which was a change toward Sauron's personality. Would he drive away the Ringwraiths? Certainly not. Sauron  sent them to bring him the ring, and any one of them would use it better than Frodo, who's only had it for several months, but then they would be wiped out by Sauron, who remains completely badass, with or without the ring.

Comment: @WadCheber Not just the Soviets. The French Revolution morphed into the Terrors almost instantly. A guy named Isiah Berlin had a theory about positive iiberty, where you apply coercion to a populace to take them to a higher level of existence, and negative liberty, where you use the minimum, not the maximum power. Problem is that you can't make people better by leaving them alone. Same goes for the Cromwell's Protectorate, after the English Civil war. The worst leader to have is the one who has the best intentions.

Comment: @chiggsy: Sauron's Ring and the nature of it are not known to Orcs in general - see the conversations they had about searching Frodo when he was captured. Also, the quoted Letter specifically says that Sauron has primary control of the wills of the Ringwraiths because he holds the Nine; otherwise, the implication is that Frodo *could* have driven away the Ringwraiths - even *with* Sauron holding the Nine, they would not be able to attack Frodo, and Tolkien says that Frodo could have indeed commanded the Ringwraiths in minor things regardless.

Comment: @chiggsy: **Would they have been immune from its power if he claimed it as an instrument of command and domination? Not wholly. I do not think they could have attacked him with violence, nor laid hold upon him or taken him captive; they would have obeyed or feigned to obey any minor commands of his that did not interfere with their errand – laid upon them by Sauron, who still through their nine rings (which he held) had primary control of their wills.**

Comment: The point is that Gandalf would have imposed a regime where people were forced to do what was best for them, or *what Gandalf thought was best for them*, with extreme brutality and lack of personal choice. In the end not only would it have been outright evil because the ring would drive Gandalf to extreme oppression justified by the end goal of a perfect society, but it would lead his subjects to reject many good things because of their association with the regime, even perhaps eventually leading them to see Morgoth or Sauron and their philosophies as good.

Answer (score 299):

The key quote from Tolkien that answers this is contained in Letter 246, with my added emphasis:

> It was part of the essential **deceit** of the Ring to fill minds with **imaginations** of supreme power.

This implies that the Ring is useless to anyone but Sauron, but it tempts you into thinking it's a source of power, and in that way it gets you to wear it, and so gains control over you.

---

In order to proceed in an investigation of this, and how to reconcile it with other statements made by Tolkien we must first establish a baseline that we're going to work from:

- It is accepted that the Ring gave some degree of "power" to Isildur, Gollum, Bilbo, Frodo and Sam, in the form of invisibility, longevity and an occasionally enhanced presence.
- Sauron was the maker of the Ring; he originally made it for his own use, and his own use only; he certainly never intended it to be used by anybody else, and he had no requirement for any of these three (as he already possessed them due to his nature as a Maia).
- Therefore these three "powers" were not an intrinsic property of the Ring intended by it's maker, but rather *side-effects* of it being used by a mortal.
- And these "powers" are actually quite minor compared to those possessed by a Maia.
- There are different kinds of "power"; these minor (by comparison) "powers" are one kind that are available to mortals as Ring-bearers, but the power to raise armies, control others, defeat Sauron and rule Middle-earth is a completely different kind altogether.

---

Now let's look at what Tolkien says about the Ring, quoting from the same source as Shamshiel's answer:

> But even if he did not wear it, that power existed and was in 'rapport' with himself: he was not 'diminished'. Unless some other seized it and became possessed of it. If that happened, the new possessor could (if sufficiently strong and heroic by nature) challenge Sauron, become master of all that he had learned or done since the making of the One Ring, and so overthrow him and usurp his place.

Here it's important to look at what Tolkien says, and *only* at what Tolkien says.  Here's what he does *not* say (and note the emphasis):

- Some other person is *controlling* the Ring.
- That other person is *gaining power* from the Ring.
- That other person is *using that power* against Sauron to defeat him.

And here's what he *does* say (emphasis again):

- Some other person has *claimed ownership* of the Ring.
- That other person has, through their own "sufficiently strong and heroic" nature, succeeded in *taking that ownership* of it from Sauron.
- And Sauron as a result *is diminished and can be defeated* by the unenhanced other person (again, if "sufficiently strong and heroic").

This is an important but subtle distinction.  In the first case the other person is using the Ring to give themselves a "level up" against Sauron, to boost their own power and defeat him that way -- but *that's not what Tolkien is saying*.  In the second they're not doing this; the power in the Ring is quite useless to them but *by being able to deny it to Sauron they diminish him* and hence (though their own natural but unenhanced strength) are able to defeat him.

As for "become master of all that he had learned or done since the making of the One Ring" - Tolkien does not actually define what he means by this.  But since the greater part of Sauron's power is in the Ring, it seems reasonable to suggest that this "mastery" actually belongs to the Ring itself rather than to the wielder (hence "since the making of the One Ring"), who only obtains the "mastery" by proxy.

> But the Ring and all its works would have endured. It would have been the master in the end.

---

Now we'll continue by looking at some other sources.  First of all, the words of Galadriel:

> Before you could use that power you would need to become far stronger, and to train your will to the domination of others.

These seem to indicate that one could use the power of the Ring, but there are two traps being set for the careless reader here.  The first one I've mentioned already:

> It was part of the essential **deceit** of the Ring to fill minds with **imaginations** of supreme power.

And the second is mentioned elsewhere by Tolkien with reference to a different character in a different situation, but must surely also apply here:

> Treebeard is a *character* in my story, not me...

So what we actually have here is Galadriel being *deceived* by the Ring into thinking it can be used, and remembering that she is a *character* in the story, not Tolkien himself, her words must only be read as being *in-character* - they shouldn't be interpreted as Tolkien describing the way things are.

The same can be said of anyone else who describes using the Ring's power in a similar situation: Gandalf, Boromir, Denethor, even Elrond when he says "I will not take the Ring to wield it".

---

I'll round things off with some other observations, also from Letter 246.  First of all Tolkien equates taking control of the Ring with *the Ring taking control of you*:

> He needed time, much time, before he could control the Ring or (which in such a case is the same) before it could control him.

Then he establishes how difficult it is to face Sauron, even if you have tried to claim the Ring (and indicating that the Ring has no power over Sauron too):

> Sauron would not have feared the Ring! It was his own and under his will.

And then he reiterates that the upper hand in a contest with Sauron does not come from your possession of the Ring, but rather from Sauron's lack of it:

> On one side the true allegiance of the Ring to Sauron; on the other superior strength because Sauron was not actually in possession.

---

In summary - the answer is "no", the Ring *wouldn't* work for anyone else in the way they *think* it would (by granting them additional power or by being able to be used as a weapon), because remember:

> It was part of the essential deceit of the Ring to fill minds with imaginations of supreme power.

But "yes", it *would* work by causing Sauron to become diminished, provided they were strong enough to be able to take and retain control of it; they would remain limited to their own native ability in any contest against Sauron, however.

Comment: I think Shamshiel's answer disproves your suggestion of "no cases whatsoever"

Comment: "Frodo - wore it for decades, longevity, invisibility and possessiveness.".Eh..say what? Frodo had it for a year or however long the whole jouney to mt doom took.

Comment: I thought frodo didnt actually wear it between ta3001 till he set off to mount doom , he kept it hidden at the bottom of a trunk in an envelope  as per gandalfs instructions for the 18years

Comment: @howler he did, but it was, nevertheless, **his**.

Comment: Are you implying that "longevity and invisibility" are not real powers?  I'd love to have those!

Comment: The implication then is that Gandalf and Galadriel were mistaken in thinking it would confer great power upon them?

Comment: @FaheemMitha - yes: "*It was part of the essential deceit of the Ring to fill minds with imaginations of supreme power*" (Letter 246).

Comment: Gollum, Sam, and Frodo expressly did not have the power to wield the One Ring, and in almost all cases did not even attempt to use it. That's why it didn't grant them anything but the most basic of power.

Comment: The Ring was not just created to enslave the Elves. "This was the essential weakness he had introduced into his situation in his effort (largely unsuccessful) to enslave the Elves, and in his desire to establish a control over the minds and wills of his servants."

Comment: @Shamshiel - this question is becoming a train-wreck of comments.  I'm going to rewrite my answer to bring my points forward more.

Comment: What about the null effect of the ring on Tom Bombadil?   There is hardly an explanation of this odd occurrence.

Comment: I am not sure that "everyone is deceived and Tolkien must be interpreted" is satisfactory.. How do you explain this one? "Would they [the Ringwraiths] been immune from its power if [Frodo] claimed it as an instrument of command and domination? Not wholly." And Sauron held the Nine, not the Ringwraiths. Or the rest of the sentence you left out? "before he could control the Ring[...] before his will and arrogance could grow to a stature in which *he could dominate other major hostile wills.*" The Ring in Frodo's hands was a "devastating weapon" he didn't know how to use.

Comment: @Shamshiel - did I say "Tolkien must be interpreted"?  I thought Tolkien was pretty explicit actually.  You're better off focussing on things I actually *did* say because you're undermining your own position otherwise...

Comment: "Treebeard is a character in my story, not me...
". I wonder if there was ever a point at which Tolkien himself was tempted by the power of the ring, in the sense of giving one of his characters the potential to bend the ring's will and use it against Sauron?

Comment: This answer seems to ascribe way too much importance and clarity to that single quote about "imaginations of supreme power."  It interprets that quote to mean that the Ring grants zero power to anyone but Sauron and that every single time any of Tolkien's characters talk about the Ring's power they are entirely misguided. So Tolkien's wisest characters are utterly deceived?  Or perhaps Tolkien himself was deceived when he wrote "The Power in Barad-Dur was shaken" when Frodo wielded the Ring for himself?  It seems pretty evident there's power to be had, and @Shamshiel's answer demonstrates that

Comment: If the ring had no power, then why would sauron even be worried about anyone else claiming it? It makes a nonsense of the story

Comment: I don't understand why Sauron is considered immune here. This is the power corrupts argument. Sauron is immune why? I don't see Sauron suddenly becoming popular and beloved if he gets this thing.

Comment: @candied_orange He does not want to be popular, he wants to corrupt or destroy Middle Earth, because that is the only way he can strike back against Valinor. You are correct about the corruption, except it was not the Ring that got him, it was Morgoth. Now his ring corrupts _you_.

Comment: " Unless some other seized it and became possessed of it." - the "other" get the power. Therefore the rest of this argument fails.

Answer (score 47):

Yes -- the One Ring seems to "work" for beings other than Sauron, as Samshiel says. The relevant factor is not just possession of the Ring, but consciously *trying* to use it to exert power over others. I think Gandalf remarked that the Ring granted Smeagol "power according to his stature" -- so all he could do was commit petty acts of evil, for which he was eventually cast out of his homeland.

As for the others, Frodo, Bilbo and Sam seldom or never used the One Ring in this way. Isildur is an interesting case. The power of the Ring *might* have helped him make Gondor stronger than it would otherwise have been, by eliminating any remaining enemies. He was ambushed and killed before he could do the same in Arnor, which may be one reason why Gondor endured while Arnor collapsed into civil war and ruin. On the other hand, Isildur was already an exceptionally capable individual, unchallenged as King, and most of his enemies had been destroyed or scattered at the Battle of the Last Alliance, so he may not have *needed* much assistance from the Ring.

I think that power proportionate to the wielder's own strength is the key point. So Smeagol only had petty abilities. Someone like Aragorn or Boromir might have become a great and merciless conqueror, much like Genghis Khan with added longevity. (He might end up like the Witch-King of Angmar, only more powerful and not owing allegiance to any other being.) Finally, a being like Gandalf, Saruman or Galadriel might have become a godlike figure, as powerful as Sauron himself or even more so.

I can see how Gandalf might have been even more terrifying than Sauron, if he was corrupted by the Ring. Sauron doesn't care if his subjects argue among themselves, drink beer, play games, or whatever as long as they obey his commands. Gandalf the Ringlord would not allow that kind of disorderly behaviour. Arguing, fighting, eating too much cake, or ignoring a "do not walk on the grass" sign would incur dire punishment. Recreation would mean gathering to sing songs in praise of Gandalf's benevolent rule.

Answer (score 31):

To bolster the answer of **Yes** already stated by other answers, we do see that Frodo was granted the power to percieve the other Rings of Power. Specifically, he was able to see Galadriel's ring:

> 'Yes', she said, divining his though, 'it is not permitted to speak of it, and Elrond could not do so. **But it cannot be hidden from the Ring-bearer**, and one who has seen the Eye. Verily it is in the land of Lorien upon the finger of Galadriel that one of the Three remains. This is Nenya, the Ring of Adamant, and I am it's keeper.'

Comment: True, but this is hardly a world-changing ability that would tip the balance if Sauron got it.

Comment: @Oldcat - Good point, I was just addressing the question as stated: "Do we ever see any actual, 'positive' effects from possessing the One Ring?" I think this counts as a positive power.

Answer (score 18):

This is more of a supplementary answer because I don't want to repeat what was mentioned in the answers already.

Short answer: No, it only works for Sauron; because it only gives him the advantages; it doesn't give anyone else any advantages of using it.

Long answer:
We really never seen any examples of Sauron himself being augmented with powers due to the ring. For example, Sauron might have had superior strength but compared to what? Before the ring? We were never given any comparisons of his strength. In fact, there is no mention of him using the ring for any other purpose than to control the other rings. He was probably just as strong as he was before together WITH IT; but once he's separated, Sauron would be weaker than ever before.

Before I continue, I'll pose a question, how does the ring make him (or anyone) else more powerful? He basically just transferred his native power into it; but that's it. He simply transferred energy, not augment it. When we transfer something, we mean we displace "something" from one container.. to another; what this means is that the transfer has weakened Sauron himself.. but the ring's purpose has been empowered; this is proven by the fact that when he was departed from the ring, it exposed his true weakened state and had to go into hiding.

Power is really all about perspective here. Like what does it mean to be truly powerful?

To discuss the meaning of absolute power we could suggest the following:

- There should not be any need for any defense mechanisms, such as the power to vanish since there's nothing to hide or run away from. We could argue that vanishing doesn't mean it's a defense mechanism, but we could still argue the point on having it as a feature.

  - However, all examples of reasons why someone would vanish is to hide and protect themselves from being discovered. When we talk about concealing, we do not think about the context of power here.
- There should not be a need to create these "ring satellites" and deceive the other races of men, dwarves, and elves into wearing them so that they'd be manipulated and controlled. The ring would enable Sauron to force any race into submitting to his will. The ring would be powerful enough by itself to get Sauron what he needed.

  - Sauron had to DISGUISE himself as "Annatar" the "lord of gifts", into creating rings to control them.
- It would be impossible for the ring to be separated from the master, there would be no weak points in it.

  - Sauron was separated from the ring by a single slash of a sword cutting his finger off, no thanks to Isildur

So with all these points in mind, we could suggest that the ring really serves one purpose, that is to deceive and weaken the enemies of Sauron, which would then allow Sauron to take advantage over them. It would NOT weaken all enemies, just the ones connected with the ring.

Examples:
The vanishing feature, though used as a defense mechanism for the ring bearer, it doesn't augment their power.. but it does give Sauron an advantage to discovering the vicinity of their location.

Being possessed, puts them at a disadvantage from being discovered as they are walking into enemy territory, risking themselves in getting caught or captured.

Comment: An excellent answer, albeit lacking any references or quotes to prove the points you're making...

Comment: I'm sorry for this, I spent a long time writing the answer, the contexts of the quotes would be extremely large since I'm describing full events. Plus to go through the material would be take more time than the answer in itself. I have read all the books, and it just seemed more convenient for myself and for other fans to understand the references from memory :).

Comment: I appreciate what you mean, but without quotes or references it's hard to determine what's canonical (e.g. from the books, letters, interviews, etc) and what's essentially a fan-theory.

Comment: Re: your comments on Sauron's powers with the ring - "While he wore it, his power on earth was actually enhanced. But even if he did not wear it, that power existed and was in 'rapport' with himself: he was not 'diminished'." - Tolkien The purpose of the One Ring was to gain power over the Elves, which failed. The Ring didn't do much for Sauron.

Comment: I also want to add...I did give examples of the Ring conferring powers and advantages over people other than Sauron, and Tolkien's statements that it would do so. :)

Comment: @Shamshiel - no, the purpose of the One Ring was to gain power over the other Rings: "*the power of the Elven-rings was very great, and that which should govern them must be a thing of surpassing potency*" (Rings of Power).  Not over the Elves, but rather over their Rings.

Comment: @JimmyShelter Yes..but that's why he wanted to gain power over the other rings - it was only a means to an end.

Comment: @Shamshiel - that's correct, but there's a subtle difference.  You shouldn't interpret it as meaning that the Ring gives you power over people; it gives you power over the other Rings and through that you can control what's accomplished by use of the other Rings.

Comment: @JimmyShelter: The One Ring was forged especially to control the wielders of the other rings, but it still helped control and dominate others. For example: "He naturally had the One Ring, and so very soon dominated the minds and wills of most of the Númenóreans." (Letter 111) Or the letter I quoted before: "his was the essential weakness he had introduced into his situation in his effort (largely unsuccessful) to enslave the Elves, and in his desire to **establish a control over the minds and wills of his servants**."

Comment: @Shamshiel, I still disagree, I read your examples, and it didn't augment any powers to the person holding it. It still showed deception. The ring spoke and made the person holding the ring.. "bigger" than they really are; but still didn't "do" anything. The whole thing is two fold, since the Orcs obeyed the ring and "crouching shape backed away, terror in its blinking eyes".. then the ring deceived them. If the Orcs did not do that, then it showed that the ring wasn't able to accomplish the power of deception.

Comment: To reiterate, the ring didn't do anything "powerful" to the user.. only to serve as an advantage to Sauron. No other user received this type of advantage. Each time they use the ring.. Sauron is the being that gets the upper hand.

Comment: One more thing concerning your comment, about Sauron's power with the ring; and the quote you mentioned. What does it mean for Sauron's power to be enhanced? We don't know what this means. The enhancement could have been the deception he instilled in his enemies by creating the rings for them. With the ring Sauron is not diminished.. he created a symbiotic relationship with it.. so his power is neither lost or gained from it, however, the weakness is that if he is separated, he is diminished.. which caused his defeat against Isildur.

Comment: If you can find one example, where the ring actually allowed the user to gain control over the minds of others.. without the user being under control of the ring.. then it's settled, that the purpose of the ring can apply to others and not just Sauron.

Comment: @sksallaj: I am puzzled by your definition of what would "augment" someone's powers. If understanding the thoughts of Orcs, terrifying Orcs, and subjugating Gollum don't qualify, what exactly would? (It was also Frodo who spoke, not the Ring, in the wider context.) Nor did Sauron get anything out of those encounters (in fact, they were critical for Frodo's success.) But as I also referenced, the only characters to carry the Ring - the Hobbits - did not have the capability to use the power of the Ring; they were only going to get mild benefits.

Comment: @sksallaj: Also, please see the letter I referenced above where Tolkien directly says that Sauron was not diminished without the Ring (unless someone else claimed it and used it), in which he also later says that someone sufficiently strong could claim the Ring and "challenge Sauron, become master of all that he had learned or done since the making of the One Ring, and so overthrow him and usurp his place." That certainly does not seem helpful to Sauron.

Comment: Shamshiel, by "augment", I mean.. if I couldn't lift a car before... now I can. If I couldn't run faster than a train.. now I can.. everything about me would improve. Regardless of whether the voice came from the ring or from frodo.. that is not a power. If I held a gun, and I told people to go away.. and they did because I had the gun.. that doesn't make ME a powerful person.. it makes me scary because I have an advantage that others don't have.

Comment: And if Tolkien said what he said to be true, why did the downfall of Sauron happen when he is separated from the ring? Why did Sauron cease to exist after destroying the ring? That's what doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The other contradiction to the orcs cowering away by Frodo commanding them to go away is.. if they were to listen to Frodo concerning the ring.. why did they cower? How can an objective to obtain the ring be accomplished if they are to cower when near that objective?

Comment: @sksallaj: Well, the Ring simply didn't grant anyone augmented powers like that because it wasn't part of the Ring. Augmented "telepathy" was pretty much all you got. Also, Sauron died both times (Numenor and Elendil/Gil-galad) while wearing the Ring. Destroying the Ring killed him because so much of him was in it. And finally, yes, that was Sauron's problem. Tolkien wrote that not even the Ringwraiths could have taken the Ring from Frodo at Mount Doom; they would have had to lure him out and wait for Sauron. You may be interested in the FAQ of the Rings.

Comment: I agree with you in your response, you didn't really disprove my point though. You quoted tolkien in saying that he wasn't "diminished" but it's contradictory because if he's ever separated from the ring, the "being" of what makes up Sauron is diminished.. but together.. they are the same as before. The original poster made is clear that he was asking whether or not the ring would augment powers like he assumed it did with Sauron. But the way the whole plot was written seemed like the ring didn't augment anyone's power at all.

Comment: Just seemed as though the ring's purpose was to make sauron's enemies weaker mentally.. whereas sauron didn't become more powerful. Just wanted to make that clear in my post. I did like your answer btw.. so I upped it!

Comment: The ring would've given Sauron domination of the elves,but as soon as he put it on the elves were aware of him so they fled and hid the rings and only started using them after Sauron was bereft of his by Isildur

Comment: Or, maybe Sauron made the ring to stay on task. Sauron's a real go getter, unlike everyone else in the story, except Feanor and his sons. It's been thousands of years he's been doing this. You make something really nice, put your vast spirt and care into it, but it's easy to become possessive, which is a theme running through Tolkien's work. The ring makes you more like Sauron, _as he was when it as forged_.  Everybody else in the story loses focus. Perhaps that is Bombadil's secret. Maybe give him the ring 3 millennia earlier and he raises an army, but now can't be bothered.

Answer (score 15):

Both answers so far have overlooked that old Tom Bombadil was unaffected by the ring when he put it on his finger. Yes, some beings (of stronger magic) would be able to take control as Gandalf and Galadriel described.

I think they were right about its corruptive abilities as well. Both would have been subject to the corruption from it through the rings that they already wore, and they had seen what became of the individuals who put on that one ring.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It's just an opinion on answers already provided. This would be better as a comment below one of the answers and not posted as answer by itself.

Comment: This is already well explained in the books - the Ring has no power over Tom.  Whether you say "yes" or "no" to the question, this doesn't actually change anything.

Comment: _'I know little of Iarwain save the name,' said Galdor; 'but Glorfindel, I think, is right. Power to defy our Enemy is not in him, unless such power is in the earth itself'._ — Tom Bombadil is indeed unaffected by the ring, but that's all: he would _not_ be able to "take control" any more than it would be able to take control over him. _Probably_, that is; it remains unclear who / what Tom Bombadil is, so something he might actually be able to do doesn't prove anything whatsoever about other guys.

Comment: I started to post this as a comment, but both of the answers at that time categorically stated that the ring had the same effect on everyone. Simply pointing out that Tom Bombadil was unaffected invalidates half of their arguments and demonstrates that what Gandalf and Galadriel stated is well within the realm of possibility. These two used stronger magic (and rings of power) on a regular basis to make Middle Earth better, which seems to make them good authorities on this matter. I do realize that this is not a definitive, independent verification.

Comment: I certainly did not mean to categorically say the Ring had the same effect on everyone. But in the case of Tom, I doubt he could use the Ring. 'It seems he has a power even over the Ring', 'Say rather that the Ring has no power over him...But he cannot alter the Ring itself, nor break its power over others.'

Comment: @JimmyShelter, " the Ring has no power over Tom. " is **NOT** an explanation.  It is a statement of "fact".  (1) Who really is Tom Bombadil?  (Middle-Earth incarnate?  "Father" Nature?)  and (2) How can the ring have NO effect on him?? 

I think a clear answer of (1) will lead to a stimulating answer for (2)

Comment: Bombadil is _not_ a great power; he's a minor, albeit very old, forest spirit. But he is _enlightened_, in the Buddhist sense; he desires nothing that the Ring can give him, and so it has no power over him.  (Gandalf says this in almost exactly these words when it's suggested to give the Ring to Bombadil for safe-keeping.)  That's really all there is to that.

Comment: Actually the point that is important is that Bombadil might not be affected by the ring, but he also cannot deny it to Sauron, or anyone else for that matter, which is the thing that must be done. We don't need to make him a monk, he could also be an immortal flake, which would be the best possible kind of immortal, really.

Answer (score 15):

You actually asked a series of questions.

It appears though that you have three main questions.

1) "Would the One Ring even work for anyone but Sauron?"

2)"But does the One Ring actually convey power to anyone but Sauron?"

3) "Do we ever see any actual, "positive" effects from possessing the One Ring?"

I'm not sure what you mean by "work". A person can wear it. It does stuff to them, it gives them some powers(ie; invisibility, long life, etc.). Positive effects? It'd be pretty cool to be invisible when you want. I'd like to live to see 500. So it works and it does convey power. Some of those powers are positive. So the answer is yes, yes, and yes.

I'm not going to get into the nitty gritty of other people's answers. However, here is a power it granted that has not been mentioned previously. It answers all three of your questions. This power "works" for Frodo not just Sauron, "coveys" Frodo power, and it's a positive effect. It gave Frodo the ability to see much further than a person not wearing the ring from the seat of seeing.

> *"At first he could see little. He seemed to be in a world of mist in which there were only shadows: **the Ring was upon him**. Then here
>   and there the mist gave way and he saw many visions: small and clear
>   as if they were under his eyes upon a table, and yet remote. There was
>   no sound, only bright living images. The world seemed to have shrunk
>   and fallen silent. He was sitting upon the Seat of Seeing, on Amon
>   Hen, the Hill of the Eye of the Men of Númenor...And suddenly he felt
>   the Eye. There was an eye in the Dark Tower that did not sleep. He
>   knew that it had become aware of his gaze. A fierce eager will was
>   there. It leaped towards him; almost like a finger he felt it,
>   searching for him. Very soon it would nail him down, know just exactly
>   where he was. Amon Lhaw it touched. It glanced upon Tol Brandir he
>   threw himself from the seat, crouching, covering his head with his
>   grey hood."*

I didn't put the entire quote as it's quite long, but the three periods I installed were a description of just about everything going on in middle earth at the time. The ring conveyed him so much sight that he could see all the way to mordor and see Sauron himself. The sight was so strong that Sauron himself felt the gaze of Frodo. So the ring did have extraordinarily enhancing features.

After Aragorn goes onto the seat of seeing.

> *"Aragorn hesitated. He desired to go to the high seat himself, hoping to see there something that would guide him in his perplexities; but
>   time was pressing. Suddenly he leaped forward, and ran to the summit,
>   across the great flag-stones, and up the steps. Then sitting in the
>   high seat he looked out. But the sun seemed darkened, and the world
>   dim and remote. He turned from the North back again to North, and saw
>   nothing save the distant hills, unless it were that far away he could
>   see again a great bird like an eagle high in the air, descending
>   slowly in wide circles down towards the earth."*

Aragorn saw hardly anything.

Christopher Tolken gave a lengthy discussion of the various drafts of Lord of the Rings and explains a difference in the final draft.

> *"... this is associated with the fact that in the final form Aragorn does go up but sees nothing it may suggest a more complex relation
>   between the power of Amon Hen and the power of the Ring... [The
>   Departure of Boromir, HoME 7]"*

I'm not going to do a lengthy research paper for each of the rings powers, when they showed themselves, how it was used, etc. That's the point of reading the books. Others have given multiple examples of this, I just wanted to add one that was left out, and (breakdown) answer the actual original question.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure why everyone's being so philosophical, the ring works just fine on Frodo.

How so? Let's recall what the ring does by reading the User's Manual, conveniently printed on the inside of the ring itself:

[image: "One ring to rule them all" in the Black Speech of Mordor]

> One ring to rule them all, one ring to find them,
> One ring to bring them all, and in the darkness bind them

Well,

1. **Bring them all**: Frodo is certainly found by/finds/happens upon a whole bunch of ring bearers - most of the human rings and all of the Elven ones. As for the Dwarf rings, well, that feature [was broken to begin with and didn't work for Mairon either](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Seven_Rings). So, **[✔]**.
2. **Find them**: When Frodo puts the ring on, I recall he is very noticeable to other rings bearers (at least, the Human rings), and vice versa. See also [this detailed answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/48800/16835). Now, probably a more experienced/corrupted/powerful bearer of the one ring would be better with this perceptive skill, but I'll put this one down as **[✔]**.
3. **Bind them**: The Elven rings avoided the binding by design, and the Dwarven rings just didn't have that effect like Mairon wanted to, so it's basically the Human rings. Given that 'to rule them' is a separate point than the 'binding', you could claim that they're still bound to the ring, and in many senses to whoever it is that's wearing it, even if he's not ruling them. So, **[sort-of-✔]**.
4. **Rule them:** This is the point about which everybody's fussing. Now, ok, maybe you don't get to boss (non-)people around that easily, and maybe you need to be a powerful Maia for that to actually work. So, **[✖]**.

Three out of Four is pretty good, considering how Frodo is not really the ruling type. It's not clear why anyone should expect the ring to do other things for him.

Comment: Interesting answer. Coming from this, in the books, the ring bearer found a like-minded group of dwarfs, humans and elves (and a wizard). They are brought together at the council of Elrond, and bound to a fellowship. And the book ends with the installation of a new Ruler whose influence seems to stretch far beyond Gondor and the realms of the humans.

Answer (score 10):

Why do we assume that the ring benefitted Sauron at all?  Every person who had it became obsessed with it and had to acquire it at all costs.  They also seemed to suffer from the delusion that it possessed "great power" beyond invisibility.  It seems reasonable to assume Sauron was affected too, and that's why he wanted it so badly - much the same way as Gollum did.  After all, everything we know about him is supposition from the other characters.  Gandalf saw Sauron's forces desperately trying to recover the ring and ASSUMED it had great magical power (or why else would he be trying to recover it), but it fact it was just a cursed "Addiction Ring" tied to Sauron's life force.

Comment: *Not everyone had to acquire it* **"at all costs."** Both Bilbo and Déagol simply found The Ring. Sméagol lost himself in the acquisition of it, but not everyone does. Frodo was just *given* it with the task of disposing of it.

Comment: @MeatTrademark Other than that statement, he does have a point. I don't believe there is proof that Sauron actually 'got stronger' after the forging of the ring. The only thing known is that it gave him control over the other ring bearers (of the lesser rings).

Comment: We are told that Sauron needs the ring in order to assume physical form.

Comment: @NateC-K  But that is because he lost his other bodies in the fall of Numenor and the battle with Gil-Galad.  It wasn't an inherent property of the ring, just the result of previous carelessness.

Comment: @NateC-K Where are we told that?  Gollum saw Sauron without the Ring and notes that he had nine fingers.

Comment: @Trademark -- Bilbo did not "simply find The Ring."  He arguably cheated in the riddle game, which was a holy rite.  He also lied about how he obtained it, which was also very out-of-character.

Answer (score 10):

There is one thing missing in this discussion as it concerns Gandalf's real stature.  Gandalf is also one of the Ainur.  He is Maiar (lesser of the Ainur) and was sent to middle earth with the other Istari (wizards) by Manwe. They Istari did so but in a diminished form which apparently included lack of full awareness of who they really were.  Regardless, when considering the effects of the ring on its wearer, Gandalf should not be grouped with Galadriel, Elrond or any others. The ring would perhaps have "unlocked" his full nature and I suspect he would have been less affected by its corrupting nature.  Gandalf in this condition would likely have been able to directly challenge Sauron 1:1 and overthrown him.  For elves and men the ring would have corrupted and betrayed them and I do not think they could have mastered the ring. Saruman (also Maiar like Sauron) probably understood this in his bones and his own corruption was likely due to visions of possessing the ring and being able to "fix" middle-earth for the better.

Unfinished Tales Part Four Chapter II 'The Istari' pp. 508–509

Answer (score 9):

To the question: **Yes.** Additionally...

1. The One Ring has awareness and a personality and seduces the wearer into doing its bidding. For an inanimate object, that's a lot.
2. Power to control other powers is power. The brain is not very powerful outside the body.
3. It seems the great power of the One Ring is to cast illusions which it uses to both seduce and empower its bearer. As advertisers can attest, this is not an insignificant power.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes.**

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13804/5789) Gollum possessed the ring for nearly 500 years while the [average Hobbit lifespan is 96 years](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Hobbits).

> when Precious goes we’ll die, yes, die into the dust.

The One Ring will **help you stay alive, [control](http://oakroadsystems.com/genl/ringfaq.htm#Q1-Powers-ControlBearers), and [dominate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/48188/5789)** as long as it can return to Sauron in the end.

Answer (score 4):

In Unfinished Tales it says if Gandalf wielded the ring against Sauron, ultimately it would lead to Sauron's destruction despite the Ring's allegiance to Sauron.

Comment: Yet Sauron's will would live on and take over, enslaving the ring bearer to domination.

Answer (score 4):

The origin of the story is the concept of the *pukelman* (actually the image of a pukelman). By creating the *pukelman*, the owner or artist transfers personal power and becomes at the same time more powerful by extending his abilities, but also more vulnerable. The *pukelman*(statue) appears for a few seconds in *The Return of the King*, and more in *The Silmarillion*. The ring is Sauron's *pukelman*.

All of Tolkien's stories re-tell plots from ancient Scandinavian German origin. It is the giant and the egg, etc., etc.

Let's compare the ring, or, better, the *palantir*, with a computer in a post-apocalyptic world. The 'new user' can use the computer to make light in the dark or use it like a mirror. But they cannot find the Wikipedia database nor start the launch sequence of the missiles.

Such is the ring - in a network it would develop its full power of Administrator, as a standalone it is a nice tablestand.

Comment: What does this have to do with the One Ring and whether it would work for anyone else, just because one doesn't know how to use the ring doesn't mean it wouldn't work if they did.

Comment: If you don't know its use, it is still usefull as a mirror or a light. Not knowing only restricts it uses but it does not makes it useless. Such is the ring, it can be used by an acolyte in a very limited way, like invisibility or a long life. A Maia can extend it's powers, first off all to make others follow in mind and action the masters plan. You need a ring to fly a nazgul. Galadriel with the one ring would mean a world without free will, only to follow her command. The elven rings are barely able to keep the one ring influence under controll as long as it is not on Saurons hand.

Comment: reference from  The Faithful Stone was published in the chapter The Drúedain of Unfinished Tales, Aghan's words "Alas! If some power passes from you to a thing that you have made, then you must take a share in its hurts." (at; tolkien gateway)

Answer (score 0):

Gandalf thinks Sauron thinks it can grant a powerful-enough person the power to overthrow him. From *The Two Towers*:

> Indeed he is in great fear, not knowing what mighty one may suddenly appear, wielding the Ring, and assailing him with war, seeking to cast him down and take his place.

Granted, it could be the Ring is implanting that delusion in Gandalf, but I think that line of thinking is a bit of a stretch, since Gandalf ultimately rejects the Ring. As has been mentioned, if the Good Guys (tm) wanted to use the Ring instead of destroy it, Gandalf would have been a prime candidate.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is a reasonable assumption that because Sauron is a servant of Morgoth/Melkor, the Ring would have worked for them and possibly sought him if he had still been a factor.

Comment: Yes it probably would've worked for Melkor but Sauron didn't want domination of Middle earth when Melkor reigned,Sauron was extremely loyal to Melkor whom in the beginning he had admired.

Answer (score -2):

According to Gandalf, one who is wise and mighty, like a wizard or Eldar, could, but the Ring would still work against them. A more powerful being like Morgoth could, but Morgoth wouldn’t bother as it would be little to him. Eru could but would have no use of it. Saruman wanted it for good reason.

Answer (score -3):

Sauron and his master, Morgoth, were a dichotomy of darkness: Morgoth corrupted nature, and Sauron exploited the corruption. Without Morgoth, Sauron was nothing, but once the world had been made with Morgoth embedded in it, Sauron had ample opportunity. All living beings, being made of the matter/cosmic data that Morgoth infected, had a hint of corruption, and were fodder for Sauron's exploitation in specific circumstances. The forging of the rings of power was a scheme by which Sauron could create these circumstances more easily. Witness, for example, the greed of the dwarves. Ownership of the ring kept by Thorin's house was a mark of rulership for his clan. The dwarven rings increased the greed of dwarf kings, which in turn led them to drive their subjects harder and more recklessly. Presumably, the One's rulership over the other rings allowed Sauron to change their power levels, corrupting those who had them with greed or else making them over-reliant on the rings' power, and thus reliant on Sauron. Sauron was a power player, setting up his dopes like pieces on a chess board, and then activating them with one master stroke. They would relate to each other in predictable ways, weakening each other and strengthening him, and when all was said and done he'd be the winner. His only weakness was that he often interfered with forces that were beyond his ken, particularly Illuvatar. After the raid on Valinor, the powerful in Middle Earth became deathly fearful of his potential, forcing him to resort to brute force and sorcery.

Comment: This answer doesn't pertain to if anyone else could wield the One Ring as Sauron did, which is the original question.

Comment: A strong enough person could claim and wield the power of the ring. They would have their OWN strengths hugely magnified, but since the Ring is essentially evil anything that person does will, eventually, turn to evil as well. The road to hell and all that. So, no, nobody can wield the Ring the same WAY as Sauron. But in the end the result would be same - the world under a dominion of dark evil under Sauron, or bright shining evil under, say, Galadriel. At least Sauron wouldn't force us to love him.