# Would a Nazgûl in possession of the One Ring seek to use it?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-one-ring, nazgul

All who came to possess the One Ring after Sauron, who possessed ambition for great deeds (basically not hobbits) have sought to master the Ring and use its power to serve their cause. Few, such as Galadriel, have successfully resisted the Ring's overpowering will and temptation.

Considering the Ring's description above, what will happen if a Nazgûl successfully retrieves the One Ring? Will he truly return it to Sauron obediently? Or will he, like all who possess a greed for power, be driven to keep, master and control the One Ring, his already-feeble will utterly unable to resist such temptation?

Comment: Related: [If one of the Ring-wraiths found the One Ring, shouldn't they be able to break free from Sauron's control?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/83757/31394)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Possible duplicate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the Nazgûl would never seek to use the Ring. In *Unfinished Tales*, specifically in the chapter *The Hunt for the Ring*, Tolkien discusses the Nazgûl and the reasons they were sent to recover the ring.

> "At length he resolved that no others would serve him in this case but his mightiest servants, the Ringwraiths, who had no will but his own, being each utterly subservient to the ring that had enslaved him, which Sauron held."

A little later in the same chapter, this is reiterated.

> "They were by far the most powerful of his servants, and the most suitable for such a mission, since they were entirely enslaved to their Nine Rings, which he now himself held; they were quite incapable of acting against his will, and if one of them, even the Witch-king their captain, had seized the One Ring, he would have brought it back to his Master."

The incapability of the Nazgûl to keep the Ring against Sauron's will was chiefly what made Sauron consider them ideal to recover it. So yes, they would have obediently returned the Ring.